# How to exit TraceDialog?

Tags: debugging

Nice question brought by my friend.

```
myFunc[x_] := x + 1; TraceDialog[Map[myFunc, Range[100]], myFunc[___]]
```

Assume you decide to interrupt after entering the dialog.

Neither `Abort[]` nor `Throw[...]` (nor `Interrupt`) do work in this case. The only remedy is `Quit[]`.

Is there a way to break from this loop?

`ExitDialog[]` doesn't break it too (thanks @Syed)

ADDENDUM: the expected result is to interrupt the calculation AND keeping the state accumulated in the kernel. I understand that I can use something like `DumpSave` etc being in the subsession caused by `TraceDialog` invocation.

Comment: `ExitDialog[]` ?

Comment: `ExitDialog` reenters the loop, sorry. will add it to the question

Comment: Use `Return[]` as many times as required (in your case 100). You will see a list of numbers `{2,... 101}` at the end and you will be out of the `TraceDialog`. Don't know how to break it up all the way with one command. I thought `ExitDialog[]` would do it but I was running an example with range `2` not `100` :  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oHVU.png).

Comment: @Syed thanks for your comment but I think it's a bit impractical to use `Return` in case of 10000000 to Infinity loop iterations :) Killing the kernel (and loosing the state) seems to be the shorter path to the same result :)

Comment: May I ask why a `TraceDialog` is to be used for such big lists? Does it deliver some  memory usage benefits?

Comment: @Syed `TraceDialog` is to be used for debugging purposes (to study the state of the system in some point that is reached from `Map`)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether that is a solution to your actual problem, but if you have control over the `TraceDialog` code you could do something like:

```
$stop = False;
TraceDialog[result=Map[If[Not@$stop, myFunc[#], Null] &, Range[100]],myFunc[___]]
```

When in the dialog, you can either use `Return[]` or `ExitDialog[]` to move on to the next iteration or evaluate `$stop=True` and then `Return[]` to exit from the loop. The return value of `Map` should contain the computed values and `Null` for the remaining non-calculated entries.

As @Syed mentioned in his comment this smells like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You might consider to describe what you try to achieve instead of asking for help for this specific approach...